# Weak Reference Finalizer Guaranteed to Run

Tags: haskell, ghc

In [The cost of weak pointers and finalizers in GHC](http://blog.ezyang.com/2014/05/the-cost-of-weak-pointers-and-finalizers-in-ghc/), Edward Yang writes (emphasis added):

> A weak pointer can also optionally be associated with a finalizer, which is run when the object is garbage collected. **Haskell finalizers are not guaranteed to run.**

I cannot find any documentation that corroborates this claim. The docs in [`System.Mem.Weak`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-Mem-Weak.html) are not explicit about this. What I need to know is, given some primitive that has identity (`MutVar#`, `MutableArray#`, `Array#`, etc.), if I attach a finalizer to it, will it reliably be called when the value gets GCed?

The reason is that I'm considering doing something like this:

```
data OffHeapTree = OffHeapTree
  { ref :: IORef ()
  , nodeCount :: Int
  , nodeArray :: Ptr Node
  }

data Node = Node
  { childrenArray :: Ptr Node
  , childrenCount :: Int
  , value :: Int
  }
```

I want to make sure that I free the array (and everything the array points to) when an `OffHeapTree` goes out of scope. Otherwise, it would leak memory. So, can this be reliably accomplished with `mkWeakIORef` or not?

Comment: Curious why you want your tree to live in unmanaged memory? For C interop?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson The garbage collector is slow when you have a lot of mutable references. In some experiments I've done with building B-trees in haskell that are around a gigabyte, the ones living in unmanaged memory can be built about 50 times faster. C interop is not something I need.

Comment: Would [compact regions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/compact-0.1.0.1/docs/Data-Compact.html) (new GHC 8.2 feature) be of any use to you? I'm guessing not because it sounds like you need to mutate parts of your structure

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Sort of. I need to store mutable arrays as part of the data structure, so compact regions are not appropriate. Although, you can actually cheat, I did go through a giant experiment and create [mutable b trees](https://github.com/andrewthad/btree/tree/e9f1525978c125e1e93bff6c1aac45f88e41a2ed) on the compact heap, but it's a hack. Also, even with this approach, you're never allowed to delete anything from the b-tree. That's why I'm turning to plain old `Ptr` for now.

Comment: Most garbage collectors don’t guarantee that finalizers will run. Language runtimes typically make a “best effort”, but will bail out under various conditions, e.g., if a finalizer throws an exception, finalization takes too long on shutdown, or the process crashes outside managed code.

Comment: @JonPurdy I don't mind those issues too much. My finalizer would just be freeing memory, so any issues related with terminating the process are non-concerns. The exception issue is the only real problem, as Yuras mentions in his ticket with GHC, because it allow some third-party library to make your code behave non-deterministically.

Comment: @AndrewThaddeusMartin: Finalizers are non-deterministic almost by design—they expose implementation details of the GC. You can use them *in addition to* (not *instead of*) deterministic resource management strategies (like `bracket`) to help reduce the impact of incorrect code on the rest of the application. If you rely on them, your code might work fine for your use case—you just need to be aware that heavy load or faulty libraries can break your assumptions.

Comment: @JonPurdy I have not previously heard the claim that heavy load can break assumptions about finalizers. What exactly does this mean? If there is too much GC pressure, do finalizers just get dropped off the queue?

Comment: @JonPurdy I spent some time reading more about finalizers (from the Java world since there's very little written on GHC's finalizers). I'm now convinced that they're not a good thing to rely on. Fortunately, bracketing will work fine in my situation, so I'll use that instead. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewThaddeusMartin: No, they won’t be dropped, but for example, if you rely on finalizers to reclaim a resource (memory, file descriptors), then because finalizers may run late or never run, those resources can be exhausted more quickly under load than they would be if you reclaimed them more eagerly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Haskell finalizers are not guaranteed to run" means that GC may not be performed (e.g. on program exit). But if GC is performed, then finalizers are executed.

**Edit:** For future readers: the statement above is not exactly correct. RTS spawns a separate thread to execute finalizers after GC. So the program may exit after GC is performed, but finalizers are not yet executed, see [this comment](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/pull/51#discussion_r127534137).

That is true in theory anyway. In practice finalizer [may not be executed](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13167), e.g. when RTS tries to execute a number of finalizers in a row, and one of then throws an exception. So I'd not use finalizers unless it is unavoidable.

Comment: Thanks. That explains the original statement from the blog post. That's a huge bummer that exceptions can mess up other finalizers that just happened to get queued together, but I agree with Simon's assessment finalizers really shouldn't throw exceptions.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Simon too. The problem is that even if you write your finalizer correctly, some other finalizer from unrelated library may break it.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to hope that there are no exceptions in finalizers in any of my deps, and then just wait to see if a space leak happens. Not my preference, but I suspect that such finalizers are rare in commonly-used libraries.

Comment: @AndrewThaddeusMartin Well, in the first place custom finalizers are rare in commonly used libraries.